# Ability to enter tab characters in a TextField?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI [`TextField`](https://v4.mui.com/components/text-fields/) that is defined as multi-line.  My goal is to enter JSON text.  I found that when I pressed the tab key, my component lost focus and focus was given to the next component on screen.  What I desire is to have the tab value (\t) entered into the string text.  Is there a recipe to disable the tab key as a navigation tool?

Comment: maybe you could use `addEventListener` for keydown on your TextField and check when evant.key == 'Tab' then append `\t` to your string and stay focus on your TextField

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, if you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> in the `input` field, the browser will switch focus to the next element. To override that behavior, you can listen to the `keydown` event and call `e.preventDefault()`, then add some code to insert the tab character at the cursor position. Below is the implementation. Note that because you are tampering with the input `value`, the undo feature doesn't work anymore:

```
<TextField
  multiline
  onKeyDown={(e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;

    if (e.key === 'Tab') {
      e.preventDefault();

      const cursorPosition = e.target.selectionStart;
      const cursorEndPosition = e.target.selectionEnd;
      const tab = '\t';

      e.target.value =
        value.substring(0, cursorPosition) +
        tab +
        value.substring(cursorEndPosition);

      // if you modify the value programmatically, the cursor is moved
      // to the end of the value, we need to reset it to the correct
      // position again
      e.target.selectionStart = cursorPosition + 1;
      e.target.selectionEnd = cursorPosition + 1;
    }
  }}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]